# Docker crontab: not found

Tags: python, django, docker

I use [django-crontab](https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab) in my project. Locally in my project work fine. But I want to use Docker. When I run Docker, I have the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/crontab: not found
```

My `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: test_api
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/django/app/
    expose:
      - "8000"
    env_file: main.env
    command: bash django_run.sh

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: test_ng
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/api.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/api.conf
      - .:/usr/django/app/
    depends_on:
      - web
    links:
      - web:web
```

django_run.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

if [ "$ADD_CRON" == "true" ]; then
    python manage.py crontab show
fi

if [ "$ADD_CRON" == "true" ]; then
    python manage.py crontab add
fi

if [ "$ADD_CRON" == "true" ]; then
    python manage.py crontab show
fi

if [ "$ADD_CRON" == "true" ]; then
    python m/usr/local/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_APP}.wsgi:application --timeout ${GUNICORN_TIMEOUT} --keep-alive ${GUNICORN_KKEP_ALIVE} -k gevent -w ${GUNICORN_WORKERS} --threads ${GUNICORN_THREADS} -b :${GUNICORN_PORT}
```

My logs:

```
test_api | /bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/crontab: not found
test_api | Currently active jobs in crontab:
test_api | /bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/crontab: not found
test_api | sh: 1: /usr/bin/crontab: not found
test_api |   adding cronjob: (649feb1a8431f09891b644aa4ba2075b) -> ('*/1 * * * *', 'cron.cron_jubs.clear_pdf_files_scheduled_job', '>> /tmp/scheduled_job.log')
test_api | /bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/crontab: not found
test_api | Currently active jobs in crontab:
test_api | [2018-03-15 14:23:41 +0000] [35] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
```

Comment: check for /etc/crontab or /etc/cron.d file in your machine, or type `which cron ` . Make sure that cron is available in your system.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Make sure that you already installed `cron` with your Dockerfile

It should be something like

```
RUN apt-get install -y cron
```

Comment: don't forget to update the package cache of apt-get via ```RUN apt-get update```